# Disable default accelerators in Win32 for push buttons

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a Win32 program that has push buttons in a window and a custom control object. When a right arrow key or left arrow key is pressed, a WM_KEYDOWN message is sent. It then gets translated to a WM_COMMAND since it is a default accelerator (left and right arrow keys). How can I disable this behavior and forward the WM_KEYDOWN message to my custom control?

Comment: Is this window a dialog window or does it use your own window procedure?  Are you calling `IsDialogMessage()`?  You can skip the `IsDialogMessage()` call for messages you don't want to have default translation.

Comment: In your custom control, handle [`WM_GETDLGCODE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/wm-getdlgcode) and return `DLGC_WANTARROWS`. [Mandatory OldNewThing read](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031126-00/?p=41703).